# why does kubernetes delete secrets after helm upgrade?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, dagster

when performing helm upgrade, I find that secrets that are created upon initial install are deleted. Why is this? The example I am using is dagster. When installing with:

`helm install dagster dagster/dagster \                                                                                                                                                       --namespace dagster \ --create-namespace`

everything starts up fine and secrets are created. When updating the image and tag and performing an upgrade with:

`helm upgrade -f charts/dagster-user-deployments/values.yaml dagster ./charts/dagster-user-deployments -n dagster`

the image is upgraded, but all secrets are deleted. Why would/ could this happen?

After running the upgrade command, I expect secrets to still be in place, and the new image to be pulled and run.

Comment: what kind of secrets are deleted and re-created? Did you specify them in `charts/dagster-user-deployments/values.yaml`?

Comment: Besides, helm3 itself stores information in Secrets located inside of Kubernetes. It does not have its own database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when performing helm upgrade, I find that secrets that are created upon initial install are deleted. Why is this?`

This is currently how helm works, here's the [issue opened](https://github.com/helm/helm-www/issues/1259) for discussion, there are several workarounds provided here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Helm will create a new secret when you install/upgrade a release and you can check all the information regarding this in `.airflow`.

By default helm will keep up to 10 revisions and whenever you run commands like `helm list, helm history, helm upgrade` it will know what it has done in its past.

Comment: I'm not using airflow, nor is there a reference. Creating a new secret doe not clarify why secrets are deleted.